# Integral of factional part

Tags: definite-integrals, fractional-part, euler-maclaurin

Given a function:

$$ F(k) = \sum_{k=600}^{999}  \left(\left(\pi^2 \right(\frac{k}{1000} + x - 1\left)^2 \right)^{10^{-7}}\right)$$
where  $0.1<x<0.35$.

The remainder term of the Euler Maclaurin sum of such function, where $p = 4$ and is given by;

$$\int_{599}^{999} \frac{\left(B_4(k - \lfloor k \rfloor\right)}{4!} \left(\frac{d^4k}{dk^4} \left(\pi^2 (\frac{k}{1000} + x - 1)^2\right)^{10^{-7}}\right) dk $$

How do I go about calculating such integrals?

Comment: Why not use  for the sum a simple little program or put it in a spreadsheet ?

Comment: A generalized approach to this will be highly appreciative, as I might be summing very large integral difference think $$ \int_{5999999999999999}^{9999999999999999} F(k) $$

Comment: @trula what kind of spreadsheet do you mean?

Comment: For example Excel , or the same in open office